# getInitialProps doesn't seem to work when using Next.js with next-redux-wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I'm trying to hook my next.js web app with redux by using 'next-redux-wrapper' HOC.

I was able to fetch data from server from getInitialProps function but after wrapping my _app.js with next-redux-wrapper the getInitialProps functions doesn't seem to work.

What do I do wrong here and how can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getItems } from '../../store/actions/itemAction'

const Index = (props) => {
  console.log(props)

  return ()
}

Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
  let items
  await fetch('http://localhost:5000/item')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { items = data })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

  return { items }
}

const mapStatetoProps = state => ({
  item: state.item,
})

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, null)(Index)
```

Comment: Are you using Next.js above version 9? if not that might be one of the issues. Have you checked the github for next-redux-wrapper examples in the README https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper?

Comment: @mdln97 Yes, I'm using the latest version of nextjs which is 9.3.5. I've checked the document of next-redux-wrapper you refer to and did the same exactly what the example does but it seems that the getInitialProps in the example doesn't seem to work either. I commented out the entire getInitialProps block in the example code, but it still works with the code being commented out, which means the getInitialProps never works in the example code.

Comment: it is also that in next.js documentation they mention that if you use next.js above 9.3 then you should use getServerSideProps or getStaticProps instead of getInitialProps

Comment: @mdln97 I see. I guess I'll have to go through the documentation. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem also exists in the following example provided by zeit / next.js . See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux-wrapper In this example the function "getInitialProps" is not called either. The effect mentioned in the readme, that the time is pre-rendered directly on the server, is therefore not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add getInitialProps on what the wrapper HOC withRedux spits out, and call it's original getInitialProps, because it's being used. I didn't figure out how to do it though

It's actually in the next-wrapper docs that getInitialProps gets swallowed, but I think it should be possible to call it.

if you do it in a page it looks like this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ locale }) => {
      const supportedChains = await getSupportedChains()
      const addresses: AddressState = { lottery6: supportedChains }
      const defaultChaiId = getDefaultChain(addresses)

      store.dispatch(addressesReceived(addresses))
      store.dispatch(switchChain(defaultChaiId))

      return {
        props: {
          ...(await getServerSideTranslations(locale!)),
        },
      }
    }
)
```